# DirectShow transform filter - how to get source filter IBaseFilter that connected to my filter input pin?

Tags: directshow

I want to check how to get source filter IBaseFilter that connected to my filter input pin?

In CheckInputType method I can allow or deny connection by media type, but I need to know more information about source filter.

Transform filter is simple, 1 inout pin and 1 output pin, based on CTransformFilter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a correct way.

In CheckConnect method you can return E_FAIL to deny connection.

You can get IBaseFilter interface from IPin using PIN_INFO struct.

Comment: You asked about connected pin, and it appears you are interested in pin, which is about to be connected only (unconnected yet).

Comment: yeah, asked incorrectly, sorry. to know info and allow / deny connection.

Answer (score 0):

You derive from `CTransformFilter`, from there:

- `m_pInput` is your input pin
- `m_pInput->m_Connected` is your input pin's connected peer
- [`IPin::QueryPinInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390432) gets you pin data including `IBaseFilter` pointer you are looking for